# Display static block in Isotope Masonry jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I'm using a WordPress theme which is using isotope jQuery plugin for displaying the pinterest like tile structure in my website. I'm trying to display a static full width tile before the other tiles for adding a small description of the site as well as for SEO purposes. But the other tiles are overlapping it to not visible clearly.

I'm looking to show a full width block at the top of the page something like this in this image.

[image: block image]

So I tried to use something like this,

```
jQuery('.index-isotope').isotope({
    'itemSelector': '.item-isotope',
    'stamp': '.code-block'
});
```

from [Masonry Isotope website](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/). But no luck. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your using the very old version 1 of isotope, `cornerStampSelector` is not an option in masonry in the newest versions, it is now `stamp`.
Try this:

```
$('#container').isotope({
 itemSelector: '.item',
 stamp: '.corner-stamp',
 masonry: {
columnWidth: 120
}
});
```

Comment: As you can see here, https://www.beinspired.in/wp-content/themes/pluto-by-osetin/assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js I'm using v3.0.1. I tried that too but no clue why no effect. Please check the code I used exactly

Comment: It appears to be working when I go to your site. What exactly are you not seeing?